# Capture HTML output from the view in RAILS and save to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to capture the output of my view file after it is rendered?

I basically want to save the full HTML output into a database after the page renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up using is the following:

```
after_filter :save_if_necessary
```

and what I stored was

```
self.response.body
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. Similar circumstance, except I was saving dynamically rendered xml.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `render_to_string`, then stick it in the db and send the string containing the rendering to the browser. See [RoR render_to_string doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000659).